# Countdown with callback with jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, countdown

I use Rendro countdown (http://github.com/rendro/countdown/)

```
    $('.countdown.callback').countdown({
      date: +(new Date) + 10000,
      render: function(data) {
        $(this.el).text(this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " sec");
      },
      onEnd: function() {
        $(this.el).addClass('ended');
      }
    }).on("click", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('ended').data('countdown').update(+(new Date) + 10000).start();
    });
```

### Styled output

```
  <div class="countdown styled"></div>

  <h2>Countdown with callback</h2>
  <p>Click on the green box to reset the counter to 10 sec.</p>
  <div class="countdown callback"></div>
```

How to automatically reset the counter (without click) back to 10 after countdown = 0 ?
I tried insert onclick function into onEnd but doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the `date` option and calling the `start([refreshRate])` method in the onEnd function after you do your `addClass`.
this should restart the countdown.

something like this:

```
 $('.countdown.callback').countdown({
    date: +(new Date) + 10000,
    render: function(data) {
        $(this.el).text(this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " sec");
    },
    onEnd: function() {
        $(this.el).addClass('ended');
        this.update(+(new Date) + 10000);
        this.start(1000);
    }
}).on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('ended').data('countdown').update(+(new Date) + 10000).start();
});
```

see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/xDy5d/

Comment: Thanks Maurizio, it works although red container continouesly bright. But I modified to: this.update(+(new Date) + 11000).start(); Once again, actually i want to reload an external page in a certain div when counter is 0. I use setTimeOut and load(url) but it's throwing errors. ;(